# Free tool/app to automate video generation out of video clips (quick selection of highlights from video clips, add intro and end texts, captions)?

Tags: video, video-editor

I have a series of video clips that students created for their projects with embedded systems.

I'm seeking for a tool that would allow me to quickly select highlights from short video clips, add transitions, add title and intro section, end text section, captions on highlights etc...).

As far as I have researched, LosslessCut seems fine to select highlights. Is there any more complete tool or can I use LosslessCut and then use some other tool to add captions, music, intro and end sections with custom text for each clip (like project name, description, some photo of schematic, etc...) ? The best solution would be to prepare some kind of text scenario as a description and to automate video generation according to this file.

Thanks in advance for advice, pointers to tools and other sources to learn from, regards.

Answer (score 1):

Davinci Resolve has a free version with a fully capable edit suite.  For quick-turnaround projects, it also includes the “cut page,” which is a simplified, minimalistic version of its  full-featured “edit page.”  For automation, Resolve is scriptable in Python and Lua, or you can avoid scripting, build project templates, replace footage, and run a render queue.  Resolve runs on Mac, Windows, and Linux.